# Is the gospel narrative hidden in the narrative of Acts 12?

Tags: acts

Close reading Acts 12, it appears the text parallels the gospel narratives. Can anyone flesh-out a verse by verse comparison?

In Acts 12:1 we read, “Now about that time Herod the king stretched forth his hands to vex certain of the church” (KJV)The word “vexed” from the Greek κακόω (*kakoō*) meaning “to oppress, afflict, harm, maltreat" (Perschbacher 217). We see the same idea in the Gospels as Herod attempted to “vex” Christ in the body causing Mary and Joseph to take Jesus and “flee into Egypt, and be thou there until I bring thee word: for Herod will seek the young child to destroy him” (Matthew 2:13, KJV). The word “destroy” is from the Greek ἀπόλλυμι (*apollymi*) (Bauer 95). So, we see Herod and Herod—the two Herods—the first Herod Antipas, oppressing Christ in the body so the he must flee into Egypt; the second Herod Agrippa, oppressing the church (the body of Christ).

There is also parallel structure in Acts 12:3 and the Gospel narrative with regards to the arrest of Peter and the arrest of Jesus. In Acts 12:3 “he proceeded further to take Peter also (Then were the days of unleavened bread)” (KJV).

The word “take” from the Greek συλλαμβάνω (syllambanō) implies “to seize, take: one as prisoner.”  Christ is also arrested on the Passover when “Then took they him, and led him, and brought him into the high priest's house. And Peter followed afar off” (Luke 22:54, KJV).

Again, the parallel structure is plain to see—Peter’s arrest in Acts mirrors Christ’s arrest in the Gospels.

Can you keep the comparisons going close reading Acts 12?

Sources:

Walter Bauer, Greek English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature (second edition), (Chicago: The University of Chicago Press, 1979), 95.

Wesley J. Perschbacher, The New Analytical Greek Lexicon (Hendrickson Publishers, 1990), 217

Holy Bible, King James Version (Camden: Thomas Nelson, Inc., 1972).

Comment: This question lacks clarity. You have not given sufficient detail about what you mean by 'parallels' the 'gospel narrative'. How can anyone 'flesh out' what you have not properly explained and defined in the first place ?

Comment: Examples added for clarity. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

A juxtaposition of Acts 12:1-17 and the Gospel narratives reveal the gospel story hidden in the text of Acts.  Why is it there?  In Acts 12:1 we read, “Now about that time Herod the king stretched forth his hands to vex certain of the church” (KJV).   The word “vexed” from the Greek κακόω (kakoō) meaning “to oppress, afflict, harm, maltreat.”  We see the same idea in the Gospels as Herod attempted “vexed” Christ in the body causing Mary and Joseph to take Jesus and “flee into Egypt, and be thou there until I bring thee word: for Herod will seek the young child to destroy him” (Matthew 2:13, KJV).   The word “destroy” is from the Greek ἀπόλλυμι (apollymi).  So, we see Herod and Herod—the two Herods—the first Herod Antipas, oppressing Christ in the body so the he must flee into Egypt; the second Herod Agrippa, oppressing the church (the body of Christ).
There is also parallel structure in Acts 3 and the Gospel narrative with regards to the arrest of Peter and the arrest of Jesus. In Acts 12:3 “he proceeded further to take Peter also (Then were the days of unleavened bread)” (KJV).

The word “take” from the Greek συλλαμβάνω (syllambanō) implies “to seize, take: one as prisoner.”  Christ is also arrested on the Passover when “Then took they him, and led him, and brought him into the high priest's house. And Peter followed afar off” (Luke 22:54, KJV).

Again, the parallel structure is plain to see—Peter’s arrest in Acts mirrors Christ’s arrest in the Gospels.

Additionally, “the same night Peter was sleeping between two soldiers, bound with two chains” (Acts 12:6, KJV),  can be compared to Christ’s crucifixion where, “Then were there two thieves crucified with him, one on the right hand, and another on the left” (Matthew 27:38).  In both narratives, Peter and Christ are framed by being positioned between two others—for Peter the guards and for Christ the thieves. But there is an additional comparison with the guards as Peter is imprisoned he is subsequently guarded by “four quaternions of soldiers to keep him; intending after Easter to bring him forth to the people” (Acts 12:4, KJV); echoing Christ’s entombment and a “watch” being set: “So they went, and made the sepulchre sure, sealing the stone, and setting a watch” (Matthew 27:66).  In both instances, soldiers are charged to “watch”—the prisoner Peter and the body of Christ (and the tomb) respectively—and both will appear “to the people” within the Passover (paschal) timeframe.

As both are being “watched” we also have the comparison of their subsequent releases which happen, arguably, before Easter.  We read in Acts: “And when he had apprehended him, he put him in prison, and delivered him to four quaternions of soldiers to keep him; intending after Easter to bring him forth to the people. Peter therefore was kept in prison: but prayer was made without ceasing of the church unto God for him” (Acts 12:4-5, KJV).

The paschal sacrifice (which was accustomed to be offered for the people's deliverance of old from Egypt). While the word “Easter” is used in the narrative the Greek word here is πάσχα (pascha) meaning “Passover.”  So, the word ‘Easter’ used here is angelized for contemporary readers denoting the Church adapting the Jewish tradition of Passover.  It is worth noting the Passover lasted many days divided where celebration of feasting (Passover meal) is a part.  Jesus was buried within this Passover timeframe.  In Mark we read “Now when Jesus was risen early the first day of the week, he appeared first to Mary Magdalene, out of whom he had cast seven devils” (16:9).

Moreover, the word for in “early” in this verse is from the Greek πρωΐ (prōï) denoting the “fourth watch of the night; a time frame from three to six o’clock” in the morning —which technically means that Jesus rose before the sunrise—by Jewish reckoning (sunrise to sunset), before the day began—which means Jesus rose before Easter morning. With this in mind, we have the comparison of Peter set free from prison before Easter and Jesus set free from death before Easter.

Additional similarities are with light shining in dark places and the “poking” of the side.  In Acts 12 we have “a light shined in the prison: and he smote Peter on the side, and raised him up” (Acts 12:7) ; compared with Christ in the tomb when “His countenance was like lightning, and his raiment white as snow” (Matthew 28:3).   The second comparison of “[smoting] Peter on the side” can be directly compared to Christ being “pierced [on] his side” (John 19:34).

The word for “smote” used in Acts 12:7 is πατάσσω (patassō) denoting “to strike gently: as a part or a member of the body; to stroke, smite: with the sword, to afflict, to visit with evils, as with a deadly disease; to smite down, cut down, to kill, slay”  While the “poke”, νύσσω (nyssō), in Acts 12:7 is not as invasive as the action of “piercing” πατάσσω in John 19:34, the word in Acts carries similar connotations—as such the comparison is clear.

Both narratives, furthermore, share a scene of divine intervention to open a portal. In Acts we have: “they came unto the iron gate that leadeth unto the city; which opened to them of his own accord” (Acts 12:10).  Compared to the Matthew where we have: “And, behold, there was a great earthquake: for the angel of the Lord descended from heaven, and came and rolled back the stone from the door, and sat upon it” (Matthew 28:2).

This comparison is too similar to dismiss out of hand—especially with the continuity of the other similarities in such a contiguous series of events. It is worth noticing that in both accounts, an angel is present. While Matthew tells us explicitly that it is an angel who “roll[s] back the stone”, to someone unaware of this divine intervention, it certainly appears that the stone rolls away “of its own accord” just as the Gate in Acts 12—where it is certainly implied that the gate moves by divine intervention as it would be foolish to take the phrase too literally and assume the gate has a will of its own.

In both narratives of Acts and the Gospels, we have Peter and Jesus meeting first with women directly after their respective “releases.”  As for Peter “when he had considered the thing, he came to the house of Mary the mother of John, whose surname was Mark; where many were gathered together praying” (Acts 12:12).

And while it is Rhoda who “harkens at the gate” in Acts, we are still at the “house of Mary.” Compared to Mary in the Gospel of John who was the first to see Jesus after the resurrection when she “turned herself back, and saw Jesus standing, and knew not that it was Jesus” (John 20:14).

This leads to the next comparison of “reporting to disciples”: “And when she knew Peter's voice, she opened not the gate for gladness, but ran in, and told how Peter stood before the gate” (Acts 12:14).   This is identical to: “And they departed quickly from the sepulchre with fear and great joy; and did run to bring his disciples word” (Matthew 28:8).  While the total number of women in the Gospel narrative is indeterminate, the narratives mention Mary Magdalene and Mary the mother of James along with Salome by name (see Matthew 28:1  and Mark 16:1 ).

Additionally, in both instances, the women are not believed: “And they said unto her, Thou art mad” (Acts 12:15).  The strong term “mad” μαίνομαι (mainomai) (used in second passive indicative (Μαίνῃ)) denotes “being out of one’s mind”  and adds dramatic effect—Peter’s presence is an impossibility—that is to say, her report is unbelievable.  Likewise, when Mary reports to the disciples that Jesus is alive we find “they, when they had heard that he was alive, and had been seen of her, believed not” (Mark 16:11). In both instances, unbelief is the common denominator.

The final comparison is that both Peter and Jesus “depart for another place” after their respective releases.  In Acts we read: “But he . . . declared unto them how the Lord had brought him out of the prison . . . And he departed, and went into another place” (Acts 12:17).  In the Gospels we have Jesus’ departure to another place when “he was parted from them, and carried up into heaven” (Luke 24:51 , cf Mark 16:19 ).

The narrative of Acts 12 and its similarities to the Gospel narratives is remarkable.  It is clear that the author intended this section of Acts to mirror the Gospel narratives. Luke must have written this narrative intentionally. The only other alternatives are: 1) it is a mistake—that is to say, the narratives are not alike; or 2) Luke was not aware of the parallel structure—which seems quite unlikely.

### Sources

Aland, Kurt, et. al. The Greek New Testament. United Bible Societies, 1975.

Bauer, Walter, et. al.  Greek English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian 
Literature (second edition). The University of Chicago Press, 1979.

Bromily, Geoffrey. Theological Dictionary of the New Testament (Abridged in One Volume). 
William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company, 1985).

Jones, R.C. “Luke’s Secret Message.” http://sensusplenior.net/wiki/01_Lukes_secret_message

Kittel, Gerhard. Theological Dictionary of the New Testament (10 Vols.). Wm. B. Eerdma ns 
Publishing Company, 1977.

Marshall, I Howard.  Acts. Tyndale New Testament Commentary. Wm. B. Eerdmans, Publishing 
Company 1989.

Perschbacher, Wesley J. The New Analytical Greek Lexicon. Hendrickson Publishers, 1990.

The Holy Bible, (King James Version). Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1972.

Thomas, Robert and Gundry, Stanly.  A Harmony of the Gospels (NAS). Moody Bible Institute 
of Chicago, 1978.

Comment: It would appear that Luke is attempting to teach us how to read the sensus plenior of the OT. By rejecting these parallels 'off the cuff' we are forever condemned to reading endless theses on the "synoptic problem".  ;P

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your question is...are you asking for resources that show the parallels between verses of Luke and Acts?  If so, the following articles may be helpful. Googling "parallels between Luke and Acts 12", brings up many articles.

One author suggested that "Luke and Acts" would be better named "1 & 2 Luke". Haven't seen any studies that bring Matthew and Mark into the parallel of Jesus and Peter (but one included Paul's travails).

1.
[*Parallels and Patterns between Luke and Acts*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/10.5325/bullbiblrese.27.4.0485.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A8549a84f76a61732bee0c2f2f15c0ff4)

Author(s): James R. Edwards
Source: Bulletin for Biblical Research , Vol. 27, No. 4 (2017), pp. 485-501
Published by: Penn State University Press
Stable URL: https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5325/bullbiblrese.27.4.0485

> All parallels considered in this study are consequently identified and
>   discussed on the basis of identical words and/or phrases, contextual
>   similarities, and (when possible) sequential agreement of data.5

2. [*A Temple Not Made with Hands*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RqZaDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=comparison%20of%20Jesus%20and%20Peter%20in%20Acts%2012&source=bl&ots=bdOPldKKiV&sig=ACfU3U2GAk_-PUwaWvGkES-ehPPt4g8neQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxoMLF5a7pAhUyYTUKHX2hCZgQ6AEwCnoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=comparison%20of%20Jesus%20and%20Peter%20in%20Acts%2012&f=false)

*A Temple Not Made with Hands:* Essays in Honor of Naymond H. Keathley
edited by Mikeal C. Parsons, Richard Walsh - 2018 - pp. 162-173

Comment: Thank you for your posting. The original question was simply "Close reading Acts 12, it appears the text parallels the gospel narratives. Can anyone flesh-out a verse by verse comparison?"  I edited to show examples... then answered in full below. Appreciate you asking and posting.

Comment: So, you presented a 'challenge' (that you had already worked out to your satisfaction)...rather than a question within BH guidelines? Was the point to showcase your own efforts? If so, mission accomplished. :)

Comment: So rather than comment on the value of the scholarship you chose ad hominem . . . hmmm.  It seemed the intent of my original question was not understood--I will take ownership of that... so yes, I posted my own answer for the sake of sharing scholarship... which is the intent of SE and BH.

Comment: It is certainly within BH guidelines to answer your own questions. What is objectionable is 'baiting'. Change your question to an honest question and then show your answer. I don't have an inclination to compare your work to that of others - the only question I have is what was the *point* of Luke to contrive the Jesus-Peter parallels. Maybe Luke is Peter with a complex. Dunno.

Comment: Ok. "Baiting" was not my intention--I edited the question a couple of different times before posting my own answer as per the first comment made Nigel. Psychometrics is indeed part of the deal when posting questions--that is to say in part how to ask the right question. I was simply curious to see if anyone could see what I see in the juxtaposition of the Acts and Gospels. Simple as that. No agenda. No emotional investment--just honest curiosity. Peace.